# Full list of RPCs - including hidden RPCs

Tags: json-rpc

Where can I find a full list of RPCs that are not listed in the output of the help command? (such as `invalidateblock` etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this in the source code which should answer your question: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/b05a89b2def301704df8f22f05a45ccf891c2b83/src/rpcserver.cpp#L268-380

It's the internal register of RPC commands that bitcoind should serve, and even includes which ought to be hidden from the help command.  `invalidateblock` is in the hidden section with three others.

Edit:

or here in this file in later version: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/623745ca74cf3f54b474dac106f5802b7929503f/src/rpc/server.cpp#L252

Answer (score 1):

#### Hidden RPC

blockchain.cpp:

```
"getblocklocations"{"blockhash", "nblocks"}
"invalidateblock",{"blockhash"}
"reconsiderblock",{"blockhash"}
"waitfornewblock",{"timeout"} 
"waitforblock",{"blockhash","timeout"}
"waitforblockheight",{"height","timeout"}
"syncwithvalidationinterfacequeue",{}
"dumptxoutset"{"path", "format", "show_header", "separator"}
```

mining.cpp:

```
"estimaterawfee", {"conf_target", "threshold"}
"generate", {}
```

net.cpp:

```
"addpeeraddress",{"address", "port"} 
"addconnection", {"address", "connection_type"}
```

misc.cpp:

```
"setmocktime", {"timestamp"}
"mockscheduler", {"delta_time"}
"echo, {"arg0","arg1","arg2","arg3","arg4","arg5","arg6","arg7","arg8","arg9"}
"echojson, {"arg0","arg1","arg2","arg3","arg4","arg5","arg6","arg7","arg8","arg9"}
```